# LocalSettings.php not found - mediawiki installation

Tags: mediawiki, bluespice

When I wanna install mediawiki 1.18.2, at the beginning of the installation process it tells that "LocalSettings.php not found." and after clicking next a blank white page appears. It tried to find LocalSettings.php on my server but no such file existed. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MediaWiki](http://mediawiki.org/wiki/mediawiki) website [installation instructions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfiguration_settings):

```
This is an index of all supported configuration options based on the DefaultSettings.php file.

Never edit DefaultSettings.php; copy appropriate lines to LocalSettings.php instead and amend them as appropriate.
```

Create your own LocalSettings.php by copying DefaultSettings.php, and then go through and delete the stuff you don't need/want.

Comment: As this question is closed I cannot answer, but in my case the problem was the LocalSettings.php file was downloaded as a .txt file so I had to change the file extension to .php